# select google suggested address in dropdown and locate it on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

A text field in which as the user types address, he gets a drop down of google suggested addresses, and then show the selected address on the map - can anyone suggest an implementation of this in html and js?

PS: I am a beginner. I browsed through some pages and got confused on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is by working through tutorials on the Google Maps Javascript API.

Here's a link to the Hello World example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

And here's a link to the auto-complete tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for:

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Comment: @gsn16 you could accept this answer as it really helps....